# Can not connect to sdf file in sql server management studio on windows mobile 6.5.3 device

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5, intermec

I am trying to connect to a sdf file on a Intermec Windows Mobile 6.5.3 device. The handheld is using SQL Server Compact 3.5. My PC has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed. I am able to connect, through SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, to a sdf file if I copy it from the handheld onto my computer. However, when I try connecting to the sdf file on the handheld I get the following error message from studio management.

```
Cannot connect to Mobile Device\Program Files\app\Data\app.sdf.
Additional information:
    Unable to configure ActiveSync for use with this application. 
    You don't have the required privileges on this machine to complete this
    operation. Contact your machine administrator for assistance. 
    (SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider)
```

One of our older applications used SQL Server Compact 3.0 and I was able to connect to the sdf file on the handheld through SQL Server 2005 Management Studio.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running SSMS as Administrator?

Comment: You know, that never even occurred to me. I went ahead and ran SSMS as Administrator and successfully connected to the SDF file on the handheld. Thanks for the suggestion. After I tried that, I was like, why did that never occur to me, lol. But then again, some of the simplest things can elude us from time to time. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. first check Your Active Sync. you can see your WM Application
2. Mobile Device-StorageCard-ProgrammeFiles-project.exe    Put Manually
   here your .sdf file
3. give this path for your connection string

`SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\Storage Card\Program Files\ProjectName\TestDatabase.sdf");`

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL Server Management Studio as an administrator